# Parsing XML with json elements

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have some sample xml listed below and I am trying to parse this data from SQL. I keep getting null records no matter how I try to pull the data in the three methods listed below. I would like to get the description of each value element into a column.

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =
```

```
'<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring xmlns:i="https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/9cb7CpYVxNhnZ2PEHP-RJz?domain=w3.org" xmlns="https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/jkqRCqx8yOt8vQG6hXaX0z?domain=schemas.microsoft.com"><KeyValueOfstringstring><Key>dateCleared</Key><Value>null</Value></KeyValueOfstringstring><KeyValueOfstringstring><Key>juvenile</Key><Value>{"code":"N","description":"No"}</Value></KeyValueOfstringstring><KeyValueOfstringstring><Key>uOF</Key><Value>{"code":"N","description":"No"}</Value></KeyValueOfstringstring><KeyValueOfstringstring><Key>disposition</Key><Value>{"code":"0","description":"0 NOT CLEARED"}</Value></KeyValueOfstringstring><KeyValueOfstringstring><Key>domViol</Key><Value>{"code":"N","description":"No"}</Value></KeyValueOfstringstring></ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>'
```

```
Select@XMLData.value('(/ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring/KeyValueOfstringstring/Value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') as 'Juvenile1',json_value('[' + @XMLData.value('(//ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring/KeyValueOfstringstring[Key/text()="juvenile"]/Value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') + ']', '$[0].description') as 'Juvenile2',json_value(@XMLData.value('declare namespace s="https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/jkqRCqx8yOt8vQG6hXaX0z?domain=schemas.microsoft.com";(/s:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring//s:KeyValueOfstringstring[s:Key="juvenile"\]/s:Value)\[1\]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '$[0].description' ) as 'Juvenile3'
```

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: SQL 2019. The code above includes an XML data sample, and T-SQL that produces the result set shown above. As I explained, I am trying to get the description from the embedded JSON values where null values appear. I tried three different SQL methods and they all produce nulls. All reproducible code examples are included.

What I am trying to achieve is a select statement that isolated the description value based on the element Key of 'juvenile' or whatever key I filter on. The desired result is a column of data for Juvenile with a value description of "NO".

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

Because #3 is not provided, you may need to adjust the output.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML =
N'<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring xmlns:i="https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/9cb7CpYVxNhnZ2PEHP-RJz?domain=w3.org" xmlns="https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/jkqRCqx8yOt8vQG6hXaX0z?domain=schemas.microsoft.com">
    <KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <Key>dateCleared</Key>
        <Value>null</Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <Key>juvenile</Key>
        <Value>{"code":"N","description":"No"}</Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <Key>uOF</Key>
        <Value>{"code":"N","description":"No"}</Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <Key>disposition</Key>
        <Value>{"code":"0","description":"0 NOT CLEARED"}</Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <Key>domViol</Key>
        <Value>{"code":"N","description":"No"}</Value>
    </KeyValueOfstringstring>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/jkqRCqx8yOt8vQG6hXaX0z?domain=schemas.microsoft.com')
    , rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('(Key/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [key]
        , c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [json]
    FROM @XMLData.nodes('/ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring/KeyValueOfstringstring') AS t(c)
)
SELECT *
    , JSON_VALUE([json], '$.code') AS code
    , JSON_VALUE([json], '$.description') AS [description]
FROM rs
WHERE ISJSON([json]) = 1;
```

**Output**

| key | json | code | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| juvenile | {"code":"N","description":"No"} | N | No |
| uOF | {"code":"N","description":"No"} | N | No |
| disposition | {"code":"0","description":"0 NOT CLEARED"} | 0 | 0 NOT CLEARED |
| domViol | {"code":"N","description":"No"} | N | No |

Comment: @DarrellKelemen, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.